# I have questions setting max/min date with uidatepicker in swift

Tags: swift, uidatepicker

I want to make my `UIDatePicker` shows the selections between two days I chose and also the time, like if I pick `2018-02-10 ~ 2018-02-14` and `10:00 ~ 12:00` with `timeInterval = 15`, it can shows those 5 days with the only 9 time selections.

I'm now doing with `.minimumDate` and `.maximumDate` but I can just make it begins from `.minimumDate` to `.maximumDate` with interval 15 mins. It means I can choose `2018-02-12 18:45` which I don't want to be chosen.

Can anyone tell me another way please?

I'm sorry for being so stupid missing my code.
Following are the codes I'm working with:

```
    let now = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour], from: Date())
    let tmr = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: Date(timeInterval: 86400, since: Date()))
    let tdat = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: Date(timeInterval: 172800, since: Date()))
    let twodat = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: Date(timeInterval: 259200, since: Date()))
    let deadlineTime = String(describing: (store.orderDeadline?.split(separator: ",")[0])!)
    let deadTime = Int(deadlineTime)!
    let noJump = now.hour! < deadTime ? true : false
    let wanttimeDatePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 200, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 200))
    wanttimeDatePicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
    wanttimeDatePicker.minuteInterval = (district.timeInterval?.decoded)!
    wanttimeDatePicker.locale = Locale(identifier: "zh_TW")
    wanttimeDatePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(wantTimePickerChanged), for: .valueChanged)
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    var firstOrderTime: Date!
    if store.orderStart == "+1 days" {
        firstOrderTime = noJump ? formatter.date(from: "\(tmr.year!)-\(tmr.month!)-\(tmr.day!) \(store.firstOrderTime ?? district.startTime!):00")! : formatter.date(from: "\(tdat.year!)-\(tdat.month!)-\(tdat.day!) \(store.firstOrderTime ?? district.startTime!):00")!
    } else if store.orderStart == "+2 days" {
        firstOrderTime = noJump ? formatter.date(from: "\(tdat.year!)-\(tdat.month!)-\(tdat.day!) \(store.firstOrderTime ?? district.startTime!):00")! : formatter.date(from: "\(twodat.year!)-\(twodat.month!)-\(twodat.day!) \(store.firstOrderTime ?? district.startTime!):00")!
    } else {
        firstOrderTime = noJump ? formatter.date(from: "\(now.year!)-\(tmr.month!)-\(tmr.day!) \(store.firstOrderTime ?? district.startTime!):00")! : formatter.date(from: "\(tmr.year!)-\(tmr.month!)-\(tmr.day!) \(store.firstOrderTime ?? district.startTime!):00")!
    }
    wanttimeDatePicker.date = (wantTimeTextField.text! == "" ? firstOrderTime : formatter.date(from: wantTimeTextField.text!))!
    wanttimeDatePicker.minimumDate = firstOrderTime
    wantTimeTextField.inputView = wanttimeDatePicker
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just edit your question and add the relevant parts of your code into it. You need to show your own efforts, because Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: I don't think it is feasible with a standard date picker. You need to create the custom picker.

Comment: @Dave Thanks for suggestion, I improved my question :)
@AlexanderGaidukov Or maybe I can only use 2 standard `UIDatePicker` to do what I want :'( ?

Answer (score 0):

To set range in datePicker you can try with this. It's work for me in swift 4.

```
    let currentDate = Date()
    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    let calendar = Calendar.init(identifier: .gregorian)
    dateComponents.year = -100
    let minDate = calendar.date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: currentDate)
    dateComponents.year = -13
    let maxDate = calendar.date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: currentDate)


    datePicker.maximumDate = maxDate
    datePicker.minimumDate = minDate
```